# bixby must use a named dispatch phrase

Tags: dispatch, bixby, hint, phrase

i am define dispatch-name,but will my define hint,throw error must use a named dispatch phrase
i dont know why,i am use Language is chinese

```
capsule-info {
  display-name (摇骰子)
  description (摇骰子)
  developer-name (chunsource)
  website-url (https://chunsource.top/)
  icon-asset (/images/icons/icon.png)
  dispatch-name(摇骰子)
  
  dispatch-aliases {
  alias (骰子)
  }

  search-keywords {
    keyword (摇骰子)
  }
}
```

```
hints {
    uncategorized {
        hint ("色盅,摇2个")
        hint ("摇骰子")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the hint file, Chinese named dispatch phrase is one of the following

- 在 %dispatch-name% 中 ...
- 在 %dispatch-name% 中 ...
- 在 %dispatch-name% 里
  ...
- 在 %dispatch-name% 里面 ...

In your case, it would be like

```
hints {
    uncategorized {
        hint ("在摇骰子里摇2个") 
        // add two more similar for marketplace requirement
    }
}
```

Please read more about reserved utterance in Chinese https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/meta-commands.zh-cn